# Call virtual parent protected function from within a Lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

How can I call a virtual Parent function using a lambda when its protected?

```
template<typename T>
class Parent
{
    protected:
        virtual int Show()
        {
            std::cout<<"Parent::Show Called\n";
        }
};

class Child : Parent<Child>
{
    protected:
        virtual int Show() final override
        {
            std::cout<<"Child::Show Called\n";

            //supposed to be in a thread in my original code.
            auto call_parent = [&] {
                //Parent<Child>::Create(); //call other parent functions..
                Parent<Child>::Show();
            };

            call_parent();
        }
};
```

The error I get is:

**error: 'int Parent::Show() [with T = Child]' is protected within this context**

Any ideas?  I'm using GCC/G++ 4.8.1 on Windows.

Comment: I asked similar question a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834845/c-lambda-friendship

Comment: [Compiles fine on clang++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22d25f9a93befadb) Combined with the question Anycorn linked, this looks like a g++ bug.

Comment: [This g++ bug?](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59483) [Or this one?](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58972)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a work-around you could call the `Parent<Child>::Show()` function via a trampoline:

```
class Child : Parent<Child>
{
    int trampoline() {
        return this->Parent<Child>::Show();
    }
protected:
    virtual int Show() final override
    {
        std::cout<<"Child::Show Called\n";
        auto call_parent = [&] {
            this->trampoline();
        };
        call_parent();
        return 0;
    }
};
```